# MySQL select from key/value pairs table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm having a lot of problems with selecting data from a table containing a key/value pairs.

I have found a few questions similar to mine, but unfortunately I'm not even close to find a solution.

[Need a MySQL query for selecting from a table storing key value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287822/need-a-mysql-query-for-selecting-from-a-table-storing-key-value-pairs)

[How to select data from a key value pair table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111954/how-to-select-data-from-a-key-value-pair-table)

Anyway, let suppose that this is my table:

```
user_id | item_id | item_amount
--------------------------------
 1      | 12      | 5
 1      | 15      | 10 
 2      | 12      | 20
 2      | 15      | 30
 3      | 12      | 1
 3      | 30      | 5
```

Now, I want to perform a search to SELECT users who are having between 5 and 50 of items of id 12 AND 15.

I was (very naively) trying something like

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM user_item 
WHERE (item_id = 12 AND item_amount BETWEEN 5 AND 50) 
AND (item_id = 15 AND item_amount BETWEEN 5 AND 50)
```

Of course, it doesn't work. Thank you for any feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM user_item
WHERE (item_id = 12 AND item_amount BETWEEN 5 AND 50) OR
      (item_id = 15 AND item_amount BETWEEN 5 AND 50)
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT item_id) = 2;
```

The `WHERE` clause filters to rows where either condition matches.  The `HAVING` guarantees that both conditions match for a given user.

Comment: Hi Gordon. I found you solution working great. I wish to give you +1 but my reputation is too low. Anyway, thanks for helping!

Comment: @ecetera: You should mark the answer as accepted. That will give Gordon points, and is the best way to say thank you.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Thank you for advice!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id FROM user_item WHERE (item_id = 12 AND item_amount BETWEEN 5 AND 50) OR (item_id = 15 AND item_amount BETWEEN 5 AND 50)
```

How about this?